# will temporarily password expired? the 1st password from salesforce

Tags: integration, authentication

hi we have a 3rd party application integrate with our Salesforce and need the user username & password+security token for the integration

i wonder will the temporarily password from salesforce expired? we used the 1st password that sent from salesforce (right after we create the user) to setup in our 3rd party application and it works but i am afraid that this 1st password from salesforce will expired. will it?

Thanks

Comment: Temporary passwords are temporary. They're not intended to be kept a long time, and you should set a permanent password. Several resources online suggest that the timeout is either 48 hours or 72 hours. There's an idea on the IdeaExchange to allow administrators to push that value higher (admin configurable). You'll find out in a couple of days if either of these values happen to be correct.

Comment: great, you are right. now i hit resetpassword error. thanks for the help